# Magento admin menu is not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I am creating a custom extension. And frontend is working fine!  But now i want to add a menu admin panel.

For that i added below code on my config.xml after `</global>`

```
<adminhtml>
<menu>
<refer>
<children>
<refer>
<title>Refer</title>
<sort_order>0</sort_order>
<action>refer/adminhtml_index/index</action>
</refer>
</children>
</refer>
</menu>
</adminhtml>
```

But nothing is coming. 
Am i doing anything worng???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <refer>
            <title>Refer</title>
            <sort_order>95</sort_order>
            <children>
                <refer>
                    <title>Refer</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>refer/adminhtml_index/index</action>
                </refer>
            </children>
        </refer>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
<menu>   
      <refer module="refer">
        <title>Refer</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <refer module="refer">
            <title>Refer</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>refer/adminhtml_index/index</action>
          </refer>        
        </children>
      </refer>    
</menu>
```

[For better understood see here.](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited)